# Array Object to Array List

Tags: javascript, arrays

Which the best way to convert this array object:

```
a = [
  {"id" : 1, "name": "a"},
  {"id" : 2, "name": "b"},
  {"id" : 3, "name": "c"}
]
```

to:

```
b = [
   [1, "a"],
   [2, "b"], 
   [3, "c"]
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let b = a.map((ite)=>[ite.id,ite.name])
```

Answer (score 2):

With map method and Object.values

```js
let newArr = a.map(x => Object.values(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each element using [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

```js
const  a = [
 {"id" : 1, "name": "a"},
 {"id" : 2, "name": "b"},
 {"id" : 3, "name": "c"},
]
const b = a.map(Object.values);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `map`

```js
a = [ {"id" : 1, "name": "a"}, {"id" : 2, "name": "b"}, {"id" : 3, "name": "c"} ]
r=a.map(o=>[o.id,o.name])
console.log(r)
```